# What version to specify for the platform iOS when writing a Podlife?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

When writing a Podfile, the first line is usually like this:

```
platform :ios, "7.0"
```

I read the [Podfile Syntax Reference](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform), which says:

> Specifies the platform for which a static library should be build.
>
> CocoaPods provides a default deployment target if one is not specified. The current default values are 4.3 for iOS and 10.6 for OS X.

So the version number for the `platform :ios` should be the same as the **Deployment Target Version** of the project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be the deployment target. This is important for pulling in specs that could have  version requirements.